# Move to next page if Table can not adjust in current page using iText

Tags: itext

I am generating a PDF report using iText. The report consists of four parts:

1. Project Info1 (A PDF Table of variable height)
2. Project Info2 (A PDF Table of variable height)
3. Requestor Info (A PDF Table of Fixed height)
4. Location Info (A PDF Table of Fixed height)

The top two information are of variable height and they can acquire certain pages. The other two are of fixed size which comes last.

I want to move the last (one or both) boxes to the next page if there is no space available to fit those boxes in current page.

If space for one box is available then place one to the current page and move other box to the next table. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try the `setSplitLate` method of `PdfPTable`